# PHP: If value exists in array, assign a new value and push all values to a new array

Tags: php, json, array-push

I want to check if JSON array in the databse has a value. Every value corresponds to a WordPress category ID. (For example, "elevator" = 120)
If it does exist, I need to push it to an array called $features so that I can later run a script that creates WordPress post where this array of exsisting numbers (IDs) are inserted to a post, like this on this example:

```
$my_post = array(
'post_title'    => $post_title,
'tax_input'    => array(
               'property_category' => array( $features )
```

---

The main code (I know I might be far off):

```
$options = explode(",",$db->options); 
$features = array();

        switch ($features) {
    case in_array("basement", $options) && "basement" != false:
        array_push($features,145);
        break;
    case (in_array("bathtub", $options) && "bathtub" != false):
        array_push($features,167);
        break;
    case (in_array("boiler", $options) && "boiler" != false):
        array_push($features,105);
        break;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `"basement" != false`?  Also can you add an example value of `$db->options` so we can see what you are processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a list of values for the options, you can create an array with the option and value combination.  Then use `array_intersect_key()` to match only the options selected (using `array_flip()` to make the option values the keys instead.  Finally use `array_values()` to remove the keys...

```
$options = ['basement', 'bathtub'];
$optionValues = ['basement' => 145, 'bathtub' => 167, 'boiler' => 105];

$features = array_values(array_intersect_key($optionValues, array_flip($options)));

print_r($features);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 145
    [1] => 167
)
```

This has the advantage of when/if you need to change the mapping, you only need to update the `$optionValues` array.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal using `if` instead of `switch`

```
if (in_array("basement", $options)) {
    array_push($features,145);
}
if (in_array("bathtub", $options)) {
    array_push($features,167);
}
if(in_array("boiler", $options)) {
    array_push($features,105);
}
```

because the switch statement evaluates, for example, to

```
switch ([]) {
   case true: ...
   case false: ...
   case true: ...
```

which does not do what you intend

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot going on here that needs to be fixed. First, let's suppose that `$options` is a fairly standard array:

```
$options = ['basement', 'bathtub'];
```

Now you set up `$features` as an array to hold the result:

```
$features = array();
```

You cannot do a lot of evaluation in a `switch` statement. In the statement `in_array("basement", $options) && "basement" != false:` you're trying to do two tests for "basement" when all you need to do is let the `switch` decide if the information is there. Just test each value buy looping through the options and testing the value

```
foreach($options as $option) {
    switch ($option) {
        case "basement":
            array_push($features,145);
            break;
        case "bathtub":
            array_push($features,167);
            break;
        case "boiler":
            array_push($features,105);
            break;
    }
}
```

Here are the [results](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2b9192ef47c787b4f47aca8684d42baeb620758f):

```
print_r($features);
```

Which returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => 145
    [1] => 167
)
```